# Limits and definition integrals involving logarithms

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Let $a \in (0,1)$ and define $$I_n(a)=\int_a^1 (\ln x)^n \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Show that limit as $a\to 0$ we have, $$\lim_{a\to 0}I_n(a)=(-1)^n \cdot n!$$

Comment: I've formatted your question using latex, is that what you meant? Or did you want the limits on the integral to be $1$ and $a$ as $$\int_1^a \ln^n x \, \mathrm{d}x$$?

Comment: Or perhaps in the other order, from $a$ to $1$.

Comment: Why should the limit as $n\to\infty$ be a function of $n$?

Comment: My guess is that you want to compute $$\int_0^1\log(x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{a\to0}\int_a^1\log(x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: yes sorry now its true

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $I_0(a)=1-a$. For $n>0$ we can use integration by parts to find, $$I_n(a)=\int_a^1\ln^n(x)dx=-a\ln^n(a)-n\int_a^1\ln^{n-1}(x)dx=-a\ln^n(a)-n I_{n-1}(a).$$ By L'Hopital's rule, $$\lim_{a\to 0}-a\ln^n(a)=\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{-\ln^n(a)}{1/a}=\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{n\ln^{n-1}(a)}{1/a}=...=(-1)^nn!\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{1/a}=0.$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{a\to 0} I_n(a)=-n\lim_{a\to 0}I_{n-1}(a)=n(n-1)\lim_{a\to 0}I_{n-2}(a)=...=(-1)^nn!\lim_{a\to 0} I_0(a)=(-1)^nn!.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using $x=e^t$ and $s=-t$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^1\log(x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{\log(a)}^0t^ne^t\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=(-1)^n\int_0^{-\log(a)}u^ne^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}
$$
Taking the limit as $a\to0$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
(-1)^n\int_0^\infty u^ne^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}
$$
Now look up the [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).